# Jquery Delay Event

Tags: jquery, delay

```
$('#cart > .heading a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#cart').addClass('active');


    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/update',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            if (json['output']) {
                $('#cart .content').html(json['output']);
            }
        }
    });         

    $('#cart').bind('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

I need to delay the removeClass on mouseleave. Can I simple add a this.delay line?

Comment: A bit of advise: instead of mouseenter, mouseleave use .hover(..., ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/window.setTimeout)

```
$('#cart').bind('mouseleave', function() {
    var $that = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){$that.removeClass('active');}, 500); //500 millisec delay
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#cart > .heading a').hover(function() {
    // clear the previously defined timeout if any
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    $(this).addClass('active');
    // do other stuff here
}, function() {
    // set timeout and save it in element's state
    // so it could be removed later on if needed
    var e = $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout(function() {
        e.removeClass('active');
    }, 3 * 1000)); // 3 sec.
});
```

This way .removeClass('active') will take action only if mouse is located outside of the element.

Comment: `this` will not be the element inside the timeout.